# ASP.net settings

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm struggling to find where some setting are being stored in a web app I have been given. If I configure it under IIS, there are some settings which are not present in the web.config (or anywhere in the app come to that if I do a text search in VS). If I change them under IIS they keep reverting to their previous values, ARGH!

Any pointers would be great!

Comment: Do they revert back to the previous setting right away, or after you publish your site again?

Comment: Thanks Jon. I've never had a site do this, so a bit stumped. Where does IIS access these? I always thought the web.config was it? What details would help if there are no general pointers?

Comment: @ajrawson. If I look in web.config the setting is not there at all, if I change the setting using IIS it keeps the old value in the dialog, if I then look in the web.config the setting is there and has the new value (however the app and IIS ignore this). Hope this is clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find them in an app.config file in an included library. You might find them in the machine.config of the hosting machine. You might find them in a proprietary database or remote xml file.

Comment: Yes! There was a config file not included in the project, so VS would not find the string on a search.

Answer (score 0):

They could be in the `Settings.settings` file, under the Properties folder.

**EDIT**:

If the machine config setting is overriding the web.config setting, you can try what was suggested here:
[Override machine.config with web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982090/override-machine-config-with-web-config)

Answer (score 0):

Try the machine level `web.config` in either

`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config` .NET 2.0 - 3.5

or

`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config` for .NET 4.0